# Best way to write and run unit tests for Brunch with Coffee

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, coffeescript, brunch

I am developing an application using [Brunch with Coffee](http://brunch.io/).

How do I write unit tests for it? I am currently mostly thinking about the model classes, so it can run without the browser, using NodeJS.

Writing the tests themselves is not the problem here, but having a good way to integrate into how brunch is set up (the way it compiles and stitches everything together and takes care of dependencies) seems a bit tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked to see how the demo app for Brunch does it:

https://github.com/brunch/todos/tree/gh-pages/test

Comment: That looks like it is running in the browser (as opposed to with node.js). But I think I'll have to do that as well. Getting everything to work on node is tricky. There seems to be support for jasmine testing built into brunch in the next release, so I'll go with this approach until then.